# Fail to Display Search Result On Image

Tags: html, css, splunk

I wish to display my search result on the webpage in table form. Unfortunately i fail to do so. My code as below:

```css
#image_overlay_panel {

position: absolute;
width:80% !important;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<panel id="image_overlay_panel">
  <html>
      <div class="image"> 
        <div style="border: 1px solid #DDD;">                
             <table>
              <title>Efficiency (KW/Ton)</title>
              <search ref="CLC_Summary"></search>
              <option name="wrap">true</option>
              <option name="rowNumbers">false</option>
              <option name="dataOverlayMode">none</option>
              <option name="drilldown">cell</option>
              <option name="count">10</option>
             </table>                                 
        </div>
      </div>
  </html>
```

The result i wish to get is display the value on right hand site on the background image.

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want? Is that seach is dropdown?

Comment: No a dropdown actually i just wish to display my search result on the image that all. And i didn't get any search result from it.

Comment: Can you add any sreen shot of output that you want?So I will get to know what exactly you want.

Comment: @Roma i upload my image files. Thxz very much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```html
<table background="download.png" border="1px solid black"> <!-- Add your image here !-->
 <tr><th>Efficiency (KW/Ton)</th></tr>
  <tr><td>CLC_Summary</td><td> - </td></tr>
  <tr><td>wrap</td><td>true</td></tr>
  <tr><td>rowNumbers</td><td>false</td></tr>
  <tr><td>dataOverlayMode</td><td>none</td></tr>
  <tr><td>drilldown</td><td>cell</td></tr>
  <tr><td>count</td><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yup~ almost the same but how should i display my result out? Any suggestion? i able to display it well when i run on different panel.